# Quartz scheduler is failing to start the cron job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Hi I am using Quartz scheduler to trigger a cron which needs to perform a host of activities. 
My Code for the same is as follow:

In the init() method of my InitServlet class, I am defining my TimerServer

```
    public class InitServlet extends HttpServlet {
      public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
         try {
            System.out.println("Starting the CRON");
            //Set the DSO Handler CRON
            TimerServer task = TimerServer.getInstance();
            task.setTask();
        }  catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Failed to start the cron");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In my TimerServer class I have the following methods

```
    public void setTask() {
        try{            
            this.setSubscriptionDailyJob();
        } catch(SchedulerException ex) {
            log.error("SchedulerException: "+ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }

private void setSubscriptionDailyJob() throws SchedulerException {
       log.info("Step 1 ");

       Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
       log.info("Step 2 ");

        JobDetail subscriptionJob = new JobDetail("subscription", "subscriptiongroup",           SubscriptionDaily.class);
 log.info("Step 3 ");
        // Initiate CronTrigger with its name and group name
        CronTrigger subscriptionCronTrigger = new CronTrigger("subscriptionCronTrigger", "subscriptionTriggerGroup");

        try {
            log.info("Subscription cron: "+Constants.SUBSCRIPTION_CRON);
            // setup CronExpression
            CronExpression cexp = new CronExpression(Constants.SUBSCRIPTION_CRON);
            // Assign the CronExpression to CronTrigger
           subscriptionCronTrigger.setCronExpression(cexp);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.warn("Exception: "+ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        scheduler.scheduleJob(subscriptionJob, subscriptionCronTrigger);    
        scheduler.start();
    }
```

In my SubscriptionDaily class :

```
public class SubscriptionDaily implements Job {    
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
      //Actions to be performed
    }
}
```

Now checking my logs, I am getting Step 1, Step 2 but not further.

My code is getting stucked at the TimerServer class itself. 
Logs wrt to Scheduler are :

```
17:24:43 INFO  [TimerServer]: Step 1       
17:24:43 INFO  [SimpleThreadPool]: Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: http-8080-1     
17:24:43 INFO  [SchedulerSignalerImpl]: Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl                                              
17:24:43 INFO  [QuartzScheduler]: Quartz Scheduler v.1.6.5 created.   
17:24:43 INFO  [RAMJobStore]: RAMJobStore initialized.                             
17:24:43 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory]: Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'  
17:24:43 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory]: Quartz scheduler version: 1.6.5               17:24:43 INFO  [TimerServer]: Step 2
```

I think a log entry is missing :
[QuartzScheduler]: Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not included common-collections jar in my library though there were no errors or exceptions being thrown anywhere in my application because of it. So I was at loss !!

I have never seen Java being so dumb before this. Is this the right behavior of java or am I expecting too much from it ?

I am also using spring in my application and Spring provides a good and simple way to handle Quartz and Java's TimerTask feature through beans. Few good and elegant tutorials are :
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/reference/scheduling.html
http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200711/combining_spring_and_quartz.html

Though the restriction in using the bean approach is, you have to hard code the cron values in the spring xml file, and so we will loose the flexibility.